# PGSQL: Long Connection Time to Postgres on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-eks, amazon-rds-proxy

I'm experiencing some **long connection time to RDS Proxy** (from 70ms to 100ms). I have found out that this is inherent to the connection as spring is logging when connection is performed and we have a notion of the time taken therefore.

I know that connecting to RDS the driver is using secure connection (SSL) and my suspicious is that this process for each connection takes a while (but 100ms its a lot).
On my application I have been using server-side-pooling (pgbouncer) and would like to remain using that by replacing it with RDS-Proxy.

Is there anything that I should be taking special care to avoid this long time connections to the database? I would like to avoid pooling on application side if possible.

I'm using Java with `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5` jdbc driver.

Comment: You could try it with `psql`. if there is a difference: the delay was caused by your middleware.

Comment: We need to see some code - if it was an RDS proxy issue, they'd be a hundred other questions like this.

Comment: Where are you connecting from and to? Is it from an in-VPC compute instance to an in-VPC database, or is it from your local PC to a database in some distant AWS region? How long are your ping times?